# A comparator that finds chains

Tags: algorithm, sorting, compare

I have a list of pairs like

```
[[4,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
```

The idea is to sort them so that the second index of the first node matches the first of the second. In the example, the list is sorted. It is assumed that the list can always be put uniquely into this form. The list is never cyclic.

Now, if it is possible I want a comparator `compare` that can obtain this form by:

```
x = [[4,1],[1,2],[2,3]]

x.sort(compare)
```

Let's assume the function `compare` returns one of two values corresponding to "bigger", and "smaller". Is this even possible, and if it is, does it depend on the sorting algorithm.

If it is not possible, is it doable with two passes (perhaps with different comparators) or any *fixed* number of passes.

I've written this in python, but my question is not intended to be specific.

Comment: I don't think this is something sorting/a comparator can do, but there will be some other algorithm for it.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to do this in one pass because the ordering you want is not a [strict partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_order#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders).  Specifically, in order for a comparator to work, it needs to obey several properties:

1. Irreflexivity: An element never compares less than itself.
2. Asymmetry: If a compares less than b, then b does not compare less than a.
3. Transitivity: If a compares less than b and b compares less than c, then c does not compare less than a.

All three of these properties are violated in your case:

1. [1, 1] compares less than itself, since you can chain [1, 1], [1, 1].
2. Two elements can be mutually chained: [1, 4] chains with [4, 1] and [4, 1] chains with [1, 4].
3. Transitivity does not hold: [1, 2] chains with [2, 3] and [2, 3] chains with [3, 4], but [1, 2] does not chain with [3, 4].

A better way of modeling your problem is trying to find an [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) through a graph.  An Eulerian path is a way of following a series of links so that you never retrace a link and such that all links are traced out.  (If you ever had those "draw this figure without retracing a line or picking up your pencil" puzzles, it's pretty much the same idea.)  In your case, the links are the pairs [a, b], and a chain through them is the same as an Eulerian path.  Fortunately, [there are many good, efficient algorithms for finding Eulerian paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Constructing_Eulerian_trails_and_circuits), and I think they're exactly what you are looking for in this context.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was not entirely clear in my question. I meant to exclude cycles and mutual chainings, I wrote something that was insufficient for resticting this. But the transitivity is the problem I was interested in. Does (a fixed number) of multiple passes with various comparisons fix it?

Comment: @Lucas- Eulerian paths aren't necessarily cyclic.  Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your comment, though.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Lucas, this is simply not a sorting problem, no matter how many times you use the words "sort" or "comparison". It is a problem of finding an eulerian path of a directed graph. There is no X >= Y relationship. [4,1] can't be directly left of [3,5] but it can be 5 places to the left.